# Rules for playing tiny characters

Tags: dnd-4e, product-identification, creature-size

I remember reading a couple years ago an article in Dragon about the rules for playing characters smaller than small in D&D 4th edition. The article also came with an adventure for such characters, or had an accompanying article in the same month's Dungeon issue, if I'm remembering correctly. I also think that it was pre-essentials, though I could be mistaken in that regard. Does anyone know which issue that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of both PCs, NPCs, and Monsters affects both size and reach.

To summarize what the PHB says, the [Wikia](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/D%26D4_Wiki) says [that](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Creature_size):

> Creatures smaller or larger than Medium have special rules relating to
>   position and attacking.
>
> **Tiny**: Four individual Tiny creatures can fit in a square, but a swarm
>   of Tiny creatures might consist of hundreds, or even thousands, of
>   them in a square. Most Tiny creatures can’t attack, and if they can,
>   they can’t attack adjacent targets. They can attack only targets in
>   the space they occupy. They can enter and end their turn in a larger
>   creature’s space.
>
> Four individual **Tiny** creatures can fit in a square. More can fit if
>   the creatures are a swarm.
>
> **Small**: Small creatures occupy the same amount of space as Medium
>   creatures. However, Small creatures cannot use two-handed weapons. If
>   a one-handed weapon can be used two-handed for extra damage, a Small
>   creature must use it two-handed and does not do extra damage.
>
> **Large, Huge, and Gargantuan**: Very large creatures take up more than 1
>   square. For example, an ogre takes up a space 2 squares by 2 squares.
>   Most Large and larger creatures have melee reach greater than 1
>   square—that is, they can make melee attacks against creatures that
>   aren’t adjacent to them. A creature’s basic body shape usually
>   determines its reach—a Large ogre has a reach of 2, but a Large horse
>   has a reach of 1.

The [Pixie](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Pixie), a Tiny PC race of HotF, has special rules:

> Pixies receive the following racial traits.
>
> **Fey Origin**
>
> **Speak with Beasts**: You can communicate with natural beasts and fey
>   beasts
>
> **Wee Warrior**: You have a reach of 1, rather than the reach of 0 that is
>   typical for a Tiny creature. You also take a -5 penalty to Strength
>   checks to break or force open objects. When wielding a weapon of your
>   size, you follow the same rules that Small creatures do.
>
> **Pixie Magic**: Pixies gain pixie dust and shrink as encounter powers.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about Dragon issues, but I know that Heroes of the Feywild contained tiny-size pixies as a playable race. The rules for being tiny in general is contained there, either in the pixie race description or a nearby sidebar.